# ContentResolver.isSyncActive() not working specifically on HTC One

Tags: android, device, synchronization, android-syncadapter

So I've been using [`isSyncActive()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#isSyncActive%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String%29) to check if a background sync is in progress and perform any caching of user actions that occur during the sync.  After the sync is complete I merge the cached list of actions with whatever happened during sync.  This method works great however, it doesn't seem to be working on an HTC One, specifically Android API 18, 4.1.2.  has anyone run into this where it doesn't work on a specific device?